What's Wrong With My Kotlin Project with NodeJS Backend?
I am learning Kotlin and making a basic project with Kotlin, NodeJS and MongoDB. I made Register and Login functions. Register form works as well and it saves data to MongoDB but login doesn't work. I used ChatGPT but it couldn't help me too.
Login.kt:
    private fun userLogin() {
        val emailAddress = emailAddress.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }
        val password = password.text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }

        val call: Call<LoginResponse> = RetrofitClient
            .getInstance()
            .getApi()
            .userLogin(emailAddress, password)

        call.enqueue(object : Callback<LoginResponse> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<LoginResponse>, response: Response<LoginResponse>)
            {
                val loginResponse = response.body()

                if (loginResponse?.error
                == false) {
                // Başarılı giriş
                    Toast.makeText(this@Login, "Hoş geldiniz, ${loginResponse.user?.firstName}!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                } else {
                    when (loginResponse?.message) {
                        "Invalid credentials" -> Toast.makeText(this@Login, "Wrong e-mail or password", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        "User not found" -> Toast.makeText(this@Login, "User not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        else -> Toast.makeText(this@Login, "Try again later", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                }
            }

            override fun onFailure(call: Call<LoginResponse>, t: Throwable) {
                Log.e("UserLogin", "Network error: ${t.message}")
                Toast.makeText(this@Login, "Connection error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }
        })
    }

user.js:

router.post("/userLogin", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const {email, password} = req.body
        const user = await User.findByCredentials(email,password)


        if(!user) {
            return res.status(401).send({error: "login failed"})
        }


        res.status(200).send({user});
    } 
    catch(error) {
        res.status(400).send({error})
    }
})


Any ideas on how to make login system as well?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
